# Writing arbitrary union of subsets as countable increasing union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and let $I$ be some arbitrary index set. Suppose for each $i\in I$ we are given some subset $U_i$ of $X$. I want to write the union $U$ of the $U_i$'s as an increasing union, i.e. I want to find subsets $V_n$ of $X$ with $V_n \subset V_{n+1}$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n = U$.

The really interesting case is the case where $I$ is infinite (possible uncountable). Choose some $i_1 \in I$ and set $V_1:=U_{i_1}$, then choose some $i_2\in I\setminus \{i_1\}$ and set $V_2:=V_1 \cup U_{i_2}= U_{i_1} \cup U_{i_2}$. Continue this process to obtain the sequence $(V_n)_n$.

$\textbf{Question}$ How can I formally prove that $U=\bigcup V_n$, i.e. why precisely does every $j\in I$ appear as an $i_n$. Right now it rather feels like only believing that this true. Would someone please provide the details, are there some Axioms in set theory which give clarity for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is to put every $V_n=U$. But obviously not what is wanted.

When $I$ is countable then by definition there is a bijection  $\phi : {\Bbb N}\rightarrow I$. Then set $V_n=\cup_{k\leq n} U_{\phi(k)}$.
Any $x\in U$ belongs to some $U_{\phi(k)}$ so to $V_n$ for every $n\geq k$.

When $I$ is uncountable  it is a bit awkward to proceed this way and it depends on what properties you really want from the $V_n$'s. At least one of them has to be an uncountable union of $U_i$'s. You may e.g. pick a countable family, let $V_1$ be the (uncountable) union of the rest and them add inductively the countable family.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot necessarily do this if $I$ is uncountable. Suppose that $I=X=\omega_1$, the set of countable ordinals, and that $U_\alpha=[0,\alpha]=\{\xi\in X:\xi\le\alpha\}$ for each $\alpha\in I$. No matter how you choose distinct $\alpha_n\in I$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, setting $V_1=U_{\alpha_1}$, $V_2=V_1\cup U_{\alpha_2}$, and so on, you’ll have

$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}V_n=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}U_{\alpha_n}\;,$$

which is the union of countably many countable sets and therefore cannot be all of the uncountable set $X$.

If $I$ is countably infinite, you can always do it: this means by definition that there is a bijection $\varphi:\Bbb Z^+\to I$, and you simply set

$$V_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^nU_{\varphi(k)}$$

for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. In your terms this amounts to letting $i_k=\varphi(k)$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 0):

The Axiom of Choice (AC) (equivalently, Zorn's Lemma or any  of hundreds of other equivalent statements) implies there are cardinals of uncountable cofinality. The cofinality $cf(k)$ of the infinite cardinal $k$ is the least cardinal $l$ such that $k=\cup_{j\in l}A_j$ such that the cardinal of each $A_j$ is less than $k.$ When $k$ is an infinite cardinal and $cf(k)=k,$ then $k$ is called regular,but if $cf(k)<k$ then $k$ is called singular. One consequence of  AC is that $k^+$ is regular for any infinite cardinal $k,$ where $k^+$ is the least cardinal greater than $k.$

Assuming AC: In particular $\omega_1=\omega^+$ is regular. Now for ordinal $i<\omega_1$ let $U_i=i$ and let $I=\omega_1.$ Then $\cup_{i\in I}U_i=\omega_1.$ But if for each $n\in N$ the set $V_n$ is a union of some of the $A_i$ and if $\cup_{n\in N}V_n=\omega_1$ then for at least one $n$ we must have $V_n=\omega_1.$

Reference topics: AC, ZF (Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory),ZFC (ZF+AC),ordinal, cardinal,cardinal ordinal, cofinality, regular cardinal, singular cardinal.